Why does VS Code's integrated terminal ignore conda activate but respects updates to PATH for Poetry in .bashrc?
I am encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal on a Linux system. Despite the terminal apparently sourcing my .bashrc file (confirmed via echo statements), it seems to selectively apply the configurations. Specifically, it respects the PATH modifications made for Poetry but ignores the conda activate command.
I want my intergrated terminal to be as similar as possible to my normal terminal when using VS Code ssh-remote. I don't understand why VS Code integrated terminal seems to be cherry picking which things to put in my PATH and what things not to put.
Relevant part of .bashrc:
# Setting up Poetry
export VENV_PATH=$HOME/.virtualenvs/venv_for_poetry
export PATH="$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"

# Conda initialization
__conda_setup="$('$HOME/miniconda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "$HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "$HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

# Activating conda environment
conda activate snap_cluster_setup_py311

Symptoms:

When opening a terminal in VS Code, the PATH is correctly modified to include the Poetry environment.
However, the Conda environment snap_cluster_setup_py311 is not activated, even though echo statements confirm that the line conda activate snap_cluster_setup_py311 is executed.

I've tried:

Ensuring .bashrc is sourced by adding echo commands.

Configuring VS Code's settings.json to explicitly use bash and source .bashrc:
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash": {
        "path": "/bin/bash",
        "args": ["-i"]
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"


Tested with both terminal.integrated.inheritEnv settings (true and false).

Added additional debugging outputs around the Conda and Poetry setups.

Created a minimal .bashrc with only Conda and Poetry settings, observed the same behavior.

I also tried:
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "/bin/bash",
            "args": ["-i", "-c", "exec bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"

that didn't work but it did echo NEW twice:
NEW
NEW
(snap_cluster_setup_py311) brando9@ampere1~ $ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.virtualenvs/venv_for_poetry/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.elan/bin
/afs/cs/software/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.virtualenvs/venv_for_poetry/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.elan/bin
/afs/cs/software/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.vscode-server-insiders/cli/servers/Insiders-5ae5a741bdb676abb667fd4896dc2a40e313db3a/server/bin/remote-cli
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/snap_cluster_setup_py311/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/condabin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.virtualenvs/venv_for_poetry/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.elan/bin
/usr/kerberos/sbin
/usr/kerberos/bin
/afs/cs/software/sbin
/afs/cs/software/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/opt/puppetlabs/bin



Also my initial user VS Code settings.json:
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "[python]": {
        "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off"
    },
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": false,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false,
        "lean4": true,
        "python": true
    },
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "python.analysis.fixAll": [
        
    ],
    "debug.focusEditorOnBreak": false,
    "accessibility.signals.lineHasInlineSuggestion": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none"
}

Why does VSCode's terminal apply the PATH changes for Poetry but not activate the Conda environment? What could be causing this selective application of .bashrc settings, and how can I ensure that the Conda environment is activated correctly?
Also posted on Discord.

Hacky solution. I told my .bashrc to not edit my PATH if the substring path is already there:
...
# Check if the CS software directory is already in the PATH. If not, prepend it to access CS software tools first.
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":/afs/cs/software/bin:"* ]]; then
    echo "Adding CS software tools to PATH"
    export PATH="/afs/cs/software/bin:$PATH"
fi
...
# Check if the Elan tools directory is already in the PATH. If not, prepend it to ensure Elan tools are prioritized.
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.elan/bin:"* ]]; then
    echo "Adding Elan tools to PATH"
    export PATH="$HOME/.elan/bin:$PATH"
fi
...
# Check if the Poetry virtual environment path is already in the PATH. If not, prepend it to ensure the Poetry environment is prioritized.
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$VENV_PATH/bin:"* ]]; then
    echo "adding virtualenvs to path"
    export PATH="$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"
fi
...
conda activate snap_cluster_setup_py311

This seems to work for me:
(snap_cluster_setup_py311) brando9@ampere1~ $ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.vscode-server-insiders/cli/servers/Insiders-5ae5a741bdb676abb667fd4896dc2a40e313db3a/server/bin/remote-cli
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/snap_cluster_setup_py311/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/condabin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.virtualenvs/venv_for_poetry/bin
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.elan/bin
/usr/kerberos/sbin
/usr/kerberos/bin
/afs/cs/software/sbin
/afs/cs/software/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/opt/puppetlabs/bin

though I really don't think this is a good solution. VScode shouldn't be cherry picking how to run my .bashrc. If it runs it again then everything should be added in the right order, especially my conda env. But it doesn't do that I guess. Otherwise the debugger doesn't work etc.
Current .bashrc:
#!/bin/bash
# When you log in to snap it runs .bash_profile
# Since it doesn't let you edit that file to source YOUR real .bashrc configurations, you need to inspect it and observe it is sourcing ~/.bashrc
# Since it is sourcing `. ~/.bashrc  you need to create that file at ~ manually every time you want to use a new server
# (this is because the first time you use a server that file doesn't exist yet at ~ (i.e. $HOME), which points to the root of the lfs server your setting up)
# My trick is to create a single .bashrc at /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brand9/.bashrc
# Then manually create a soft link to point to the file every time I set up a new server e.g.,
# if the working version is on afs
# ln -s /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/.bashrc $HOME/.bashrc
# or somehwere else:
# ln -s /lfs/mercury1/0/brando9/evals-for-autoformalization/.bashrc $HOME/.bashrc
# then do cd $HOME; ls -lah to confirm the soft link point to where you expect:
# e.g., .bashrc -> /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/.bashrc
# confirm your at the server you expect
# hostname e.g., output mercury1.stanford.edu
# now you can put whatever you want in your .bashrc (located at afs and soft linked at ~ for this server)!
# e.g., you can activate the conda env and install the cuda versions you need want
# note: the cuda and conda versions you need might depend on the specific server since the specific cuda version might only work for the gpu that server has

# ---- Brando's scaffold .bashrc file ----

# - Approximately source the sys admin's .bashrc (located at /afs/cs/etc/skel/.bashrc)
# since snap is set up badly and it needs the reauth command to re-authenticate randomly somtimes, you need to make sure reauth cmd is available
# Check if the CS software directory is already in the PATH. If not, prepend it to access CS software tools first.
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":/afs/cs/software/bin:"* ]]; then
    echo "Adding CS software tools to PATH"
    export PATH="/afs/cs/software/bin:$PATH"
fi
# 
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Loads all readable shell scripts from /afs/cs/etc/profile.d/ if the current shell is not a login shell.
#if [ "x$SHLVL" != "x1" ]; then # We're not a login shell
    for i in /afs/cs/etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            . $i
        fi
    done
#fi

# Sets the maximum number of open file descriptors for the current process to 120,000.
ulimit -n 120000
# commented out so sourcing .bashrc doesn't output things to screen.
#ulimit -Sn # to check it's 120000
#ulimit -Hn # to check it's 120000

# - The defaul $HOME is /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9 but since you want to work in a specific server due to otherwise conda being so hard you need to reset what home is, see lfs: https://ilwiki.stanford.edu/doku.php?id=hints:storefiles#lfs_local_server_storage  
export LOCAL_MACHINE_PWD=$(python3 -c "import socket;hostname=socket.gethostname().split('.')[0];print('/lfs/'+str(hostname)+'/0/brando9');")
mkdir -p $LOCAL_MACHINE_PWD
export WANDB_DIR=$LOCAL_MACHINE_PWD
export HOME=$LOCAL_MACHINE_PWD

# - set up afs short cuts
# since you are loged in to afs this moves you to your local computer
cd $HOME
export TEMP=$HOME
export AFS=/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9
export DFS=/dfs/scratch0/brando9/

# - prompt colours
BLACK='\e[0;30m'
RED='\e[0;31m'
GREEN='\e[0;32m'
BROWN='\e[0;33m'
BLUE='\e[0;34m'
PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
CYAN='\e[0;36m'
LIGHT_GREY='\e[0;37m'
DARK_GREY='\e[1;30m'
LIGHT_RED='\e[1;31m'
LIGHT_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
LIGHT_BLUE='\e[1;34m'
LIGHT_PURPLE='\e[1;35m'
LIGHT_CYAN='\e[1;36m'
WHITE='\e[1;37m'

BACK_DEFAULT_COLOR='\e[m'

HOST_PART='$(hostname | cut -d. -f1)'
export PS1="\[$LIGHT_GREY\]\u@$HOST_PART\[$LIGHT_GREEN\]\w\[$LIGHT_GREY\] \$ \[$LIGHT_CYAN\]"

# -- If you use wandb you might need this:
export WANDB_API_KEY=TODO
export HF_TOKEN='your_token_here'
export OPENAI_KEY='your_openai_key_here'

# - Start this linux env with the gpu with most memory available
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=5
export LEAST_GPU_ID=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.used --format=csv,nounits,noheader | awk '{print NR-1 " " $1}' | sort -nk2 | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$LEAST_GPU_ID

# -- Lean, ref: https://github.com/brando90/snap-cluster-setup?tab=readme-ov-file#lean-in-snap
# Check if the Elan tools directory is already in the PATH. If not, prepend it to ensure Elan tools are prioritized.
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.elan/bin:"* ]]; then
    echo "Adding Elan tools to PATH"
    export PATH="$HOME/.elan/bin:$PATH"
fi

# # not needed, if issues see: https://ilwiki.stanford.edu/doku.php?id=hints:gpu
# export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:$PATH
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# -- poetry, we are setting up poetry before conda so that we don't accidentally use poetry's python version, see: https://github.com/brando90/snap-cluster-setup?tab=readme-ov-file#poetry
# assumes mkdir $HOME/.virtualenvs has been ran
export VENV_PATH=$HOME/.virtualenvs/venv_for_poetry
# assume poetry has been installed as explained here: https://github.com/brando90/snap-cluster-setup?tab=readme-ov-file#poetry
# Check if the Poetry virtual environment path is already in the PATH. If not, prepend it to ensure the Poetry environment is prioritizede. ref: https://chat.openai.com/c/500163c3-086a-426b-b5ca-ade6b4819c95
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$VENV_PATH/bin:"* ]]; then
    echo "adding virtualenvs to path"
    export PATH="$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"
fi

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('$HOME/miniconda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "$HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "$HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

# very similar to the conda init code above, will leave it out since snap seems to be working e.g., it can find conda command just fine with the above code, note above code **does** have to be at the end
# export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

# activates the conda base env
source $HOME/miniconda/bin/activate

# activate snap_cluster_setup default conda env
conda activate snap_cluster_setup_py311
# echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'

# nvhtop: https://github.com/peci1/nvidia-htop, RS: https://discord.com/channels/488822282664280084/489073165851688960/1230951660671602818
if ! command -v nvidia-htop.py &> /dev/null; then
    pip install nvidia-htop
fi
alias nvhtop='nvidia-htop.py --color -l 100'

